# Is the size of the set created by the Kleene star always infinity? What about its closure?

Tags: logic, formal-languages

My notes state

> $L^+$ denotes $LL^*$and is the closure of L under concatenation. That
>   is, it is the smallest language that includes L and all strings that
>   are concatenations of strings in L

Isn't the size of a Kleene star always infinity (except when the language is the empty set). For example L={a} then $L^*=\{a,aa,aaa,aaaa...\}$ therefore $|L^*|=\infty$ therefore $|LL^*|=\infty$

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct, but the spelling in the title wasn't: you might like to know that  Kleene pronounced his name with two syllables: like "cleany"

Comment: Yeap for non-empty languages KIeene star gives you an infinite language.

Comment: @Rob Arthan  "clay-nee" not "clean-y"

Comment: @BrianO: not according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stephen_Cole_Kleene or anybody I have ever heard pronounce the name.

Comment: @Rob Arthan  Did you read more than the first line of the article? It says: "Although his last name is commonly pronounced /ˈkliːniː/ KLEE-nee or /ˈkliːn/ kleen, Kleene himself pronounced it /ˈkleɪniː/ KLAY-nee.[1]  His son, Ken Kleene, wrote: 'As far as I am aware this pronunciation is incorrect in all known languages. I believe that this novel pronunciation was invented by my father.'" ... Logicians pronounce it the way he did.

Comment: @BrianO: thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Rob Arthan you're welcome. The remark by his son, also a professor, is pretty funny. The wikipedia article gives a reference for their source and his quote: http://foldoc.org/Stephen%20Kleene, which in turn cites... a gopher document (dead-end for me).

Answer (score 3):

No. If $L=\{1\}$, where $1$ denotes the empty word, then $L^+ = L$ and hence is finite.
As you observed, if $L$ is empty, then $L^+$ is empty. In all other cases,
$L^+$ is infinite.